# Can not connect to postgresql on localhost using ssl client certificate with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to connect to postgresql on localhost using ssl client certificates via django. However I get the following error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
```

**I have tried the following**

1. I can connect to a remote postgresql database via 
   the django application (using a set of different 
   certificates)
2. I can connect to the local database (using the same 
   ssl certificates that does not work in django) using 
   psql.
3. I can connect to the database on localhost via the django shell and psycopg2 connection using the following code

```
psycopg2.connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=analyticslayer user=al-app password=... sslmode=verify-ca sslcert=/home/al-app/.postgresql/ps-analyticslayer-1-postgresql-al-app-ca.crt sslkey=/home/al-app/.postgresql/ps-analyticslayer-1-postgresql-al-app-key.pem sslrootcert=/home/al-app/.postgresql/vintercapital.com-ca.crt")
```

4. I have also verified that the certificates are okay using openssl verify

I am using 
django 2.2.6
postgresql 10
ubuntu 18.04

would really appreciate some help with this problem
/ Hakan

**UPDATE**

As requested, this is the postgresql log (/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log) when I try to connect via django. The connection attempt is part of an automated deployment script that restarts the database.

```
2020-02-27 13:06:33.444 UTC [4627] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-02-27 13:06:33.474 UTC [4627] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-02-27 13:06:33.477 UTC [4627] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 4634) exited with exit code 1
2020-02-27 13:06:33.477 UTC [4629] LOG:  shutting down
2020-02-27 13:06:33.498 UTC [4627] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-02-27 13:06:33.619 UTC [6293] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-02-27 13:06:33.619 UTC [6293] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-02-27 13:06:33.621 UTC [6293] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-02-27 13:06:33.648 UTC [6294] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-27 13:06:33 UTC
2020-02-27 13:06:33.668 UTC [6293] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-02-27 13:06:34.205 UTC [6301] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2020-02-27 13:06:34.715 UTC [6304] postgres@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

*Multiple of these messages*

2020-02-27 13:06:39.831 UTC [6334] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 85: "local   all             postgres                                md5"
2020-02-27 13:06:39.834 UTC [6335] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2020-02-27 13:08:05.351 UTC [6478] al-app@analyticslayer FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
2020-02-27 13:11:43.679 UTC [6618] al-app@analyticslayer FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
2020-02-27 14:03:48.243 UTC [6293] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
```

When I log in using psql from my local machine. The log looks like this

```
2020-02-28 17:18:59.525 UTC [11842] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: Success
```

When I log in to django shell and execute the psycopg2 code the log registered nothing. However  `conn.closed` gives me 0.

Comment: Can you look in the server's log file to see if it has a clearer error message?  (For password authentication, it usually does.  For ssl, it usually does not, but it is worth a try.)

Comment: For what its worth, as for now I simply connect over unix socket, but I still want to be able to do the above